# Unable to make a connection to ALM 12.5 using vb macro

Tags: vba, excel, alm

I have 2 ALM's (11 and 12.5), with the below code, i am able to connect to ALM11, but it says invalid user name and password for 12.5 ALM, (user credentials are correct)

```
Function ALM_Connection(ByRef TDConnection, server, user, pwd)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fileArray
    almLogin.connectionMessage.ForeColor = vbBlue
    Set TDConnection = CreateObject("tdconnection")
    sUserName = user
    sPassword = pwd
    If Trim(sUserName) = "" Or Trim(sPassword) = "" Then
        almLogin.connectionMessage.ForeColor = vbRed
        almLogin.connectionMessage.Caption = "Please Enter the data and click on 'Authenticate'"
        ALM_Connection = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    almLogin.connectionMessage.Caption = " Please Wait.. "
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    TDConnection.InitConnectionEx server
    TDConnection.Login sUserName, sPassword

    If (TDConnection.loggedin <> True) Then
        almLogin.connectionMessage.ForeColor = vbRed
        almLogin.connectionMessage.Caption = "Invalid UserName or Password"
        ALM_Connection = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        almLogin.connectionMessage.Caption = "Logged In Successfully"
        ALM_Connection = True
    End If

End Function
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Does 12.5 work with early binding instead of late binding / `CreateObject`?

Comment: @Mat's Mug :can you give please give me a hint on how to check that?

Comment: Meh, I don't think it has anything to do with late/early binding. FWIW you can early-bind a dependency by browsing to its library in the Tools/References menu, and then you could do `Set connection = New TDConnection` instead of `CreateObject`. Reason I don't think it's that is because you *are* getting a response ("invalid username/password" is a response), so the thing works. Are you handling runtime errors anywhere? Are the two versions connecting to the same place?

Comment: I will try it, 2 projects in 2 ALM so not connecting to the same place. my requirement is collecting defects from 4 different alms to excel,every thing was working till updating to ALM12.5 :( (3 alm's in with version 11, just one in 12.5)

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the below syntax to create the OTA object

> Set TDconnection = CreateObject("tdapiole80.tdconnection")

However, Since the connection and authentication are enclosed inside "On Error Resume Next", the error message may not actually reflect the real cause.

So, this is what I would do to debug.

1. Remove the On Error Resume Next and check whether the code can create a TDConnection Object
2. Installing the correct version of HP ALM Addin.
3. Console out "err.description" to understand the real cause

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your code it throws message "Invalid UserName or Password" in any case when TDConnection.loggedin property is not True, but it can be because of other reason, e.g. wrong OTAClient.dll library (they are not backward compatible). So in general case you should register your ALM client on the machine (server_url/qcbin -> Tools -> Register client) and then try one more time.

If it doesn't help, you can try to rewrite your code using sample from official documentation http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/topic96.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try and refrain from *just* linking code samples in your answer. There's nothing wrong with posting the link, but I would suggest that you might post some relevant snippets from the link, in the event that the link goes down.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the Project unavailable. Also check if you have access to any one of the projects in the v12.5.

Thanks.